# Can I have SVG polygon with edge interactions and fill

Tags: javascript, svg, jquery-svg

I have a polygon with point coordinates.
I want them as polygons with holes and each side of a polygon with different color.

I have the code for basic Polygon with same color for all edges . I need the polygon with different colored edges.Is that possible ??

```css
.square {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 20;
}
```

```html
    <svg width="300" height="300">
        <polygon class="square" points="20,20 290,20 290,130 20,130"></polygon>
    </svg>
```

Possible interactions should be first edge over the second, second edge over the first and the miter effect.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
**

Can I achieve it with polygon , lines or paths? Valuable suggestions
    please.

**

Comment: I suspect you will not be able to do this with a single polygon. You could make multiple paths and assign the stroke values. This will allow you to create an outline of a polygon with different stroke colors and the ability to control caps, as well as layer positions.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Based on your comment, it sounds like there is a lot more going on that you're not sharing.

Comment: You'd need multiple polygons or multiple paths as it's one colour per element.

Comment: @RobertLongson - Not just the colors but overlays too.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to write a solution for that yourself too.

Comment: Nice question. I suspect one could write some JS to take a standard SVG POLYGON shape and build a GROUP containing individual POLYGONS or different fill colors, with one for each side. You'd pass the corner style in as a parameter. Of course, I could be over complicating this as it could just be that you draw the whole thing in Illustrator and be done with it! It's not clear from your question how flexible you want this to be so it would be good to give us more detail.